# Why two unicode-characters are not allowed in xkb?

Tags: x11, unicode, xkb

I wonder why a sequence of Unicode-characters is not allowed on one key-press in xkb. Eg. I use the Indian keyboard for typing in Devanagari. This keyboard is based on the [inscript keyboard layout](http://sanskrit.indiatyping.com/images/sanskrit-Inscript-Layout.jpg). In this layout, there are four characters (let's say complex characters) that are not found in the xkb version (Indian). Those characters are composed of three figures, and if one wants to type them, he/she is supposed to sort all three of them. The characters and their composition is as follows -

1. त्र = त (U0924) + ् (U094D) + र (U0930)
2. श्र = श (U0936) + ् (U094D) + र (U0930)
3. ज्ञ = ज (U091C) + ् (U094D) + ञ (U091E)
4. क्ष = क (U0915) + ् (U094D) + ष (U0937)

In other operating-systems, this layout works fine. Why does it not work in UNIX? What has to be done to allow this kind of programming?